# GIMP Alternative for Android

Tags: gimp, android

Is there any good photo editing software for Android, similar to GIMP? That software should have option for manipulating with layers, color editing and most important features that desktop version of GIMP has.

Comment: a basic google search should bring you some results

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works in and OS based PC, and Android - including Remix Mini...And Chromebook

Pixlr, is a web-based photo editing tool there are a couple flavors, but that will get you started.

JLH